# How to suppress staticinitialization with Junit 5 and mockito without using powermock

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit4, junit5, spring-test

I am facing an issue while creating Mock objects with Mockito.static method. If the class contains any static initializers , these initializers are executing while creating mocks. I don not want to execute these static initializers. We should use only Junit 5 and Mockito framework and we should not use Powermock.

Example:

```
public class StaticUtils {
    static {
        
        System.out.println("StaticUtils Initlizling...........");
    }

    private StaticUtils() {}

    public static List<Integer> range(int start, int end) {
        return IntStream.range(start, end)
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static String name() {
        return "Baeldung";
    }
}
```

Junit:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MockedStaticUnitTest {

    @Test
    void givenStaticMethodWithNoArgs_whenMocked_thenReturnsMockSuccessfully() {
       // assertThat(StaticUtils.name()).isEqualTo("Baeldung");
        assertEquals(StaticUtils.name(), "Baeldung");

        try (MockedStatic<StaticUtils> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticUtils.class)) {
            utilities.when(StaticUtils::name).thenReturn("Eugen");
            assertEquals(StaticUtils.name(), "Eugen");
        }

        assertEquals(StaticUtils.name(), "Baeldung");
    }
}
```